# How did "to snowball" originate?

Tags: vocabulary

To *snowball* means to increase gradually. For example,

> Inflation has snowballed in the last year.
>
> The debate snowballed into a heated argument.

I am not able to understand the word *snowballed.* Does it have something to do with snow and ball? How did this meaning develop?

Comment: [definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snowball#Verb); [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=snowball&allowed_in_frame=0); [snowball effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_effect)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be asked on ELL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of "snowballing" comes from a snowball (a clump of snow often used for throwing).  If you get a snowball and roll it downhill, it will get larger and larger as it moves down the hill and more snow sticks to it.

With the assistance of gravity, it increases in speed as it gets more and more massive. Until it can eventually move pretty damn fast unaided.

Answer (score 2):

If you roll a small snowball around on ground thinly covered with snow, it gets bigger.

[image]

You can see the bare grass there where the snowball was rolled over and picked up the snow.

Answer (score 1):

@Jacobm001 explained what snowball is. And I think,  it is a result of "metaphoric use"

it is not related something to do with "snow" and "ball" but rather the action that creates the meaning.